# Values not set in $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a login form and script on `index.php`. The problem is that the PHP code doesn't seem to pick up the fields I put in.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user'])||isset($_POST['pass'])){
        ?>
            <script>
                $('#login-drop').addClass('open');
                console.log('Opening');
            </script>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['user'])){
            if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
                login();
            } else{
                ?>
            <script>
                $('#pass-group').addClass('has-error');
                console.log('Password has error.');
            </script>

                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>
                $('#user-group').addClass('has-error');
                console.log('User has error');
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing was entered'; 
    }

    function login(){
        echo 'Both username and password was entered.';
    }
?>
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="?login">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in</legend>
                <div class="form-group" id="user-group">
                  <label for="user" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="pass-group">
                  <label for="pass" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Even if I enter the fields it still says `Nothing was entered.` I can't see the problem but I tend to overlook things a lot.

PS. I'm using Bootstrap so the classes should work. I've tested them.

Comment: It picks up only those fields which have a `name` attribute.  `id` isn't used when the field is submitted.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: You are missing the input names and hence the POST cant read your data.

Comment: (This problem could have been isolated if using the browser developer tools to inspect transmitted data; this in turn would have led to a more useful title/description..)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854205/php-post-not-working?lq=1 (good duplicate) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220473/post-not-passing-any-variables?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940291/php-not-able-to-access-post-values?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your input element `name`s, otherwise their values do not get submitted. `id`s may also be useful for your JavaScript code, but they don't solve that problem.

So what you want to do is

```
<input name="user" id="user" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added **"name"** attribute to your `<input>` tag ie

```
<input class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text" name="user">
```